How to create type for AccountId32 using Polkadot-JS api
I am writing integration test using Polkadot-JS api.
On the Substrate chain side, I have this structure:
pub type NodeKey = AccountId32;

#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum StorageKey {
    PubKey(NodeKey),
}

I am passing StorageKey in a pallet extrinsic.
On the integration test side:
  const nodeKey = polkadotApi.registry.createType('NodeKey', '123456d9c3626ba725e78d71234564b4d07e84f0388465bc7eb992e3e1123456');

  const storageKey = polkadotApi.registry.createType('PalletNodesStorageKey', nodeKey);


When I execute this, I get below error:
 Error: createType(NodeKey):: DoNotConstruct: Cannot construct unknown type NodeKey


Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Why not just do
const nodeKey = polkadotApi.registry.createType('AccountId32', '123456d9c3626ba725e78d71234564b4d07e84f0388465bc7eb992e3e1123456');  ?

And if you want custom types in the PJS API, you can add them using something like this api.registry.register(yourDefs)
